# Error must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple currency converter using C, but for some reason it keeps giving me the error "error must be a modifiable lvalue".
I have checked up my code, and I don't see any problems with it. Any help?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    void main(){
        float jod_usd=1.41, usd_jod=0.71, jod_eur=1.26, eur_jod=0.8, currency;
        char ic;
        int f;
        printf("Enter the number of your conversion option to continue...\n1-  Convert from JOD\n2-  Convert to JOD\n");
        scanf("%d",&f);
        printf("Enter the character of your second currency to continue...\nU - - USD\nE - - EUR\n");
        scanf("%c",&ic);
        printf("Enter your amount:\n");
        scanf("%f",&currency);
        if(f==1&&(ic='U'||ic='u')){
            printf("%.2f JOD  - - %.2f USD\n",currency,(currency*jod_usd));
        }
        if(f==1&&(ic='E'||ic='e')){
            printf("%.2f JOD  - - %.2f EUR\n",currency,(currency*jod_eur));
        }
        if(f==0&&(ic='E'||ic='e')){
            printf("%.2f EUR  - - %.2f JOD\n",currency,(currency*eur_jod));
        }
        if(f==0&&(ic='U'||ic='u')){
            printf("%.2f USD  - - %.2f JOD\n",currency,(currency*usd_jod));
        }
        system("pause");

    }
```

Comment: `(ic='U'||ic`....hmmmm

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm not, I just wrote it in capitals to make it clear that it's about C Programming. I'm sorry if it sounded like that, I'll edit it.

Comment: As Sourav Ghosh pointed out, use `==` instead of `=` when testing the value of `ic`.

Comment: Those `ic=<something> || ic=<other>` are not good, @Cor

Comment: @Cor better now, still, that's not a very good title. :)

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first. Write a title that will help not only you but also future readers of this Q&A. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh new to the forums, sorry! Thanks so much! But now, I'm having a problem with executing the program. I cannot input a character for some odd reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The mistake of using `=` instead of `==` caused this.

First, you're changing the value of `ic` unwantedly.

Second, due to operator precedence,

```
  (ic='U'||ic='u')
```

is the same as

```
  ((ic='U'||ic) = 'u')
```

where, the result of `(ic='U'||ic)` is **not** an lvalue.

Comment: Ohh! I thought you used 1 `=` sign instead of two! Still new to the language, learning it in university. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not just a simple bug? You usually don't assign in a condition. If I fix that, then you get some program flow:

```
Enter the number of your conversion option to continue...
1-  Convert from JOD
2-  Convert to JOD
1
Enter the character of your second currency to continue...
U - - USD
E - - EUR
Enter your amount:
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
    float jod_usd=1.41, usd_jod=0.71, jod_eur=1.26, eur_jod=0.8, currency;
    char ic;
    int f;
    printf("Enter the number of your conversion option to continue...\n1-  Convert from JOD\n2-  Convert to JOD\n");
    scanf("%d",&f);
    printf("Enter the character of your second currency to continue...\nU - - USD\nE - - EUR\n");
    scanf("%c",&ic);
    printf("Enter your amount:\n");
    scanf("%f",&currency);
    if(f==1 && (ic=='U' || ic=='u')){
        printf("%.2f JOD  - - %.2f USD\n",currency,(currency*jod_usd));
    }
    if(f==1&&(ic=='E'||ic=='e')){
        printf("%.2f JOD  - - %.2f EUR\n",currency,(currency*jod_eur));
    }
    if(f==0&&(ic=='E'||ic=='e')){
        printf("%.2f EUR  - - %.2f JOD\n",currency,(currency*eur_jod));
    }
    if(f==0&&(ic=='U'||ic=='u')){
        printf("%.2f USD  - - %.2f JOD\n",currency,(currency*usd_jod));
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: I just tested it and got the same results.. I'm not quite sure what's causing it honestly. Any ideas?